# Kafka mirroring Failed to find leader for Set (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to mirror Kafka data between two AWS Kafka/Zookeeper clusters, both running version 0.8.2.1.

I can access source cluster Zookeepers from the target cluster Kafka instances, list topics, etc. However when trying to run this **command**:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker 
                                  --consumer.config /opt/kafka/config/mirror-consumer.properties 
                                  --num.streams 1 
                                  --producer.config /opt/kafka/config/mirror-producer.properties 
                                  --whitelist=".*"
```

I get the following **error**:

```
WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [...] from broker [...] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at kafka.api.TopicMetadata$$anonfun$readFrom$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TopicMetadata.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:78)
    at kafka.api.TopicMetadata$.readFrom(TopicMetadata.scala:36)
```

What would be the best way to debug this error? I've read several posts online but they indicate a whole array of causes, from network connectivity to disk space issues.
I would appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a critical bug in Kafka 0.8.2.1 version which has not been fixed since 2015:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2082
"failed due to Leader not local for partition"

It looks like there is no way to deal with this short of upgrading Kafka to the latest version. Based on other posts I found online it looks like Kafka mirroring does not work between different versions of Kafka, so this is another thing to consider.